# Acces denied when using psexec

Tags: cmd, local, psexec

I try to use the psexec program via command line to run program on another pc connected to my local network.
What i try to accomplish?:

I want to code a program that lets user send links ( to ebay auction e.g. ) to chosen pc from local network, for that i want to use psexec as a main component.

What is my problem?:
When i try to dry use psexec ( e.g. `psexec \\another-pc cmd` ) i got acces denied every time i try this ( no matter what machine is target ).

What i tried?:
So far i tried to fetch login credentials in command line:

```
psexec \\some-pc -u someuser -p password cmd
```

I also tried to disable UAC on target PC with this line:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

I think i could do that easily if i knew a passwod for -p part, but none of my pcs have passwords set, all default users are admins,

My question is, does windows set any default password for local network acces like masterkey or smth ?

I'm a bit confused on what shall i do next.
If anyone know what should i do to overcome this obstacle i would be gratefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use psexec remotely you should be an admin on a remote PC. And since Windows does not allow remote connections for admins with an empty password so you'll either need to set a password for your admin user or create a new user.

BTW your question is more suitable for superuser, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so i need to create new user with admin privilages on target pc and when i acces it it will look smth like this:
MY_PC_NAME/user_name password: user_pasword ?